# How to make a plane to rotate only on one axis?

Tags: c#, animation, 3d, unity-game-engine

How to make a plane to "look" at the camera by rotating on only on one axis?

For example, I have a plane with a texture of smoke coming from the pipe. If I walk around the pipe the plane should always be facing the camera, rotating along the y axis. But the direction of the smoke should not change, therefore, along with the x and z axes, the plane should not rotate.

**Here is a code example which helps to rotate the plane on all axes:**

```
void Update() 
{
transform.LookAt(Camera.main.transform.position, -Vector3.up);
}
```

**How to make it rotate only on one axis?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One approach to this is to store the object's original rotation in a Vector3 using transform.eulerAngles. You can then create another Vector3 to store the object's rotation after the LookAt function has completed. You can then set the object's rotation to a new Vector3 using only the y value from the second variable and using the original x and y values. It would look something like this:

```
void Update()
{
    Vector3 originalRotation = transform.eulerAngles;
    transform.LookAt(Camera.main.transform.position, -Vector3.up);
    Vector3 newRotation = transform.eulerAngles;
    transform.eulerAngles = new Vector3(originalRotation.x, newRotation.y, originalRotation.z);
}
```